# How to add metadata columns in list view for Ubuntu 16.04 with Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, metadata

I have tried this line of code but it has not worked:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-columns
```

I tried following steps given [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/515783/how-to-adding-metadata-columns-in-nautilus-ubuntu) but
I am stuck on step 2 because there seems to be no attachment to download and hence cannot proceed.

Would be grateful if somebody to clarify or suggest new methods. Thanks.

Comment: Hee, I am on this 'quest' as well... after some searching I found this script: https://gist.github.com/escoand/cf1605f7e0410b319fcb